# Result type of applying polymorphic function to each tuple element

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14

I'm trying to write a transform function for tuples, however all examples I found either apply a function to tuple elements passed by reference or use non-unary functions.

I however would like to have something like

```
std::tuple<float, int> t(3.f, 2);
// returns std::tuple<bool, bool>:
auto r1 = transform(t, [] (auto v) { return v > decltype(v)(2); });
// returns std::tuple<float, int>:
auto r2 = transform(t, [] (auto v) { return v + decltype(v)(1); });
```

The question I got regarding this is:
Is it possible to determine the result type of applying an unary function to each tuple element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let `std::make_tuple` do the type inference for you. You do need an `index_sequence` pack expansion to build the `make_tuple` call:

```
template <typename T, typename F, std::size_t... I>
auto tmap(T&& t, F&& f, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
  return std::make_tuple(f(std::get<I>(std::forward<T>(t)))...);
}

template <typename T, typename F>
auto tmap(T&& t, F&& f) {
  return tmap(std::forward<T>(t),
              std::forward<F>(f),
              std::make_index_sequence<
                std::tuple_size<
                  typename std::decay<T>::type
                >::value>{});
}
```

[C++11-compatible demo at Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/487cb7070a4a00ea).

Note that the returned tuple will store a value when `f` returns a reference type. If you actually want to store references you need the more complicated helper function:

```
template <typename T, typename F, std::size_t... I>
auto tmap(T&& t, F&& f, std::index_sequence<I...>) {
  return std::tuple<decltype(f(std::get<I>(std::forward<T>(t))))...>{
    f(std::get<I>(std::forward<T>(t)))...
  };
}
```

Comment: (I wonder if pass-by-universal-ref `F&& f` will become the new default way of passing function objects.)

Comment: what about `return std::make_tuple(..)`?

Comment: @DyP I assume pass-by-universal will become standard practice in C++14, when capture-initializers provide an easy source of move-only functors. And yes, `std::make_tuple` makes it much simpler. I'm starting to think I should have let you write this answer and made myself some breakfast.

Comment: Worked great (this version and one using make_tuple) - I thought I tried that, but I guess it was my usual lack of std::decay/std::remove_reference. @DyP: I actually always use F&& _except_ when I want to store it in a member, then I do void set(F func) { m_func = std::move(func); }

Comment: @RichardVock The question about `F&&` is more about function objects; in the C++11 Standard Library, inherited from pre-universal-reference C++98/03, function object typically are taken by-value. If you'd expect them to be copied similarly to StdLib algorithms, `F&&` would change behaviour.

Comment: Hmm.. note that `make_tuple` slightly differs from your original version using `decltype` (e.g. if `f` returns an lvalue/rvalue reference, a copy is stored in the `tuple`). `forward_as_tuple` is closer to the original, I think, but has the same possible lifetime issues if `f` returns a reference.

Comment: @DyP `forward_as_tuple` stores *everything* as a reference, and is thus poorly suited as a return type.